# True value of a parameter in statistics

Tags: statistics, notation, parameter-estimation, hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood

Let us consider a statistics model
$X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n\sim^{i.i.d} f(x,\theta)$,
where $f(x,\theta)$ is a probability density function with a parameter $\theta$. 
Let $\theta_0$ be a true value of $\theta$.

In the setting above, **I often get confused about the difference between $\theta$ and $\theta_0$.** For exmaple, why should we write
\begin{align*}
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
H_0 : \theta=0, \\
H_1 : \theta\neq 0
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align*}
instead of
\begin{align*}
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
H_0 : \theta_0=0, \\
H_1 : \theta_0\neq 0.
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align*}
In fact, I have not seen the latter notation in books and papers.

**My opinion** 
$\theta$ is an unknown generic parameter and not fixed. I understand $\theta$ like a variable (not  a randam variable). On the otherhand, $\theta_0$ is fixed.
If $\theta_0=3$, we have $H_0: 3=0$ in the latter notation. It cannot make sense. Is my opinion correct?

Comment: I prefer $\theta=...$, since this is the parameter which we are testing. Nevertheless it is a question of definition.

Comment: I am not sure what "Let $\theta_0$ be a true value of $\theta$" is suppose to mean.  The actual  value of $\theta$? A possible value of $\theta$?  You often see $H_0: \theta=\theta_0$ and $H_1: \theta\not =\theta_0$ for some specific $\theta_0$

Comment: @Henry: Thank you for your comment! $\theta_0$ is the actual value of $\theta$. In other words, the data follow a distribution of $f(x,\theta_0)$. Indeed, we use $\theta_0$ to denote some specific value in hypothesis test, but this is not the case here.

Comment: If the actual value of $\theta$ is $3$ and your test fails to reject $H_0:\theta=0$ then you have made a Type II error.  This is not uncommon, as your test may not have been powerful enough or you may have been unlucky.